# How can I fix the error shown below in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

console.error: The action 'Navigation/OPEN_DRAWER' was not handled by any navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.

My code is shown below.

MainTabScreen.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

import DashboardScreen from './DashboardScreen';
import OpportunitiesScreen from './OpportunitiesScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './EditProfileScreen';
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator();
const OpportunitiesStack = createStackNavigator();
const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const DashboardStackScreen = (props) => (
  
  <DashboardStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#7b68ee',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
          }
      }}>
          <DashboardStack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardScreen} options={{
          title:'Dashboard',
          headerLeft: () => (
            
              <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={25} backgroundColor="#7b68ee" onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}></Icon.Button>
            
          )
          }} />
  </DashboardStack.Navigator>
  );
  
  const OpportunitiesStackScreen = (props) => (
  <OpportunitiesStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#7b68ee',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
          headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
          }
      }}>
          <OpportunitiesStack.Screen name="Opportunities" component={OpportunitiesScreen} options={{
          headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={25} backgroundColor="#7b68ee" onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}></Icon.Button>
          )
          }} />
  </OpportunitiesStack.Navigator>
  );
  
  const ProfileStackScreen = (props) => (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#7b68ee',
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        }}>
            <ProfileStack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{
            headerLeft: () => (
              <Icon.Button name="ios-menu" size={25} backgroundColor="#7b68ee" onPress={() => props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}></Icon.Button>
          )
            }} />
    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
    );

const MainTabScreen = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Dashboard"
      activeColor="#fff"
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Dashboard"
        component={DashboardStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Dashboard',
          tabBarColor: '#009387',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-home" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Opportunities"
        component={OpportunitiesStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Opportunities',
          tabBarColor: '#1f65ff',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-aperture" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileStackScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
          tabBarColor: '#694fad',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Icon name="ios-person" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default MainTabScreen;
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { 
  NavigationContainer, 
  DefaultTheme as NavigationDefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme as NavigationDarkTheme
} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import { 
  Provider as PaperProvider, 
  DefaultTheme as PaperDefaultTheme,
  DarkTheme as PaperDarkTheme 
} from 'react-native-paper';

import { DrawerContent } from './screens/DrawerContent';

import MainTabScreen from './screens/MainTabScreen';
import SupportScreen from './screens/SupportScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen';
import BookmarkScreen from './screens/BookmarkScreen';

import { AuthContext } from './components/context';

import RootStackScreen from './screens/RootStackScreen';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const App = () => {
  // const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  // const [userToken, setUserToken] = React.useState(null); 

  const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = React.useState(false);

  const initialLoginState = {
    isLoading: true,
    userName: null,
    userToken: null,
  };

  const CustomDefaultTheme = {
    ...NavigationDefaultTheme,
    ...PaperDefaultTheme,
    colors: {
      ...NavigationDefaultTheme.colors,
      ...PaperDefaultTheme.colors,
      background: '#ffffff',
      text: '#333333'
    }
  }
  
  const CustomDarkTheme = {
    ...NavigationDarkTheme,
    ...PaperDarkTheme,
    colors: {
      ...NavigationDarkTheme.colors,
      ...PaperDarkTheme.colors,
      background: '#333333',
      text: '#ffffff'
    }
  }

  const theme = isDarkTheme ? CustomDarkTheme : CustomDefaultTheme;

  const loginReducer = (prevState, action) => {
    switch( action.type ) {
      case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN': 
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'LOGIN': 
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: action.id,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'LOGOUT': 
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: null,
          userToken: null,
          isLoading: false,
        };
      case 'REGISTER': 
        return {
          ...prevState,
          userName: action.id,
          userToken: action.token,
          isLoading: false,
        };
    }
  };

  const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(loginReducer, initialLoginState);

  const authContext = React.useMemo(() => ({
    signIn: async(foundUser) => {
      // setUserToken('fgkj');
      // setIsLoading(false);
      const userToken = String(foundUser[0].userToken);
      const userName = foundUser[0].username;
      
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', userToken);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      // console.log('user token: ', userToken);
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', id: userName, token: userToken });
    },
    signOut: async() => {
      // setUserToken(null);
      // setIsLoading(false);
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken');
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' });
    },
    signUp: () => {
      // setUserToken('fgkj');
      // setIsLoading(false);
    },
    toggleTheme: () => {
      setIsDarkTheme( isDarkTheme => !isDarkTheme );
    }
  }), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async() => {
      // setIsLoading(false);
      let userToken;
      userToken = null;
      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      // console.log('user token: ', userToken);
      dispatch({ type: 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN', token: userToken });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  if( loginState.isLoading ) {
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
    <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
      { loginState.userToken !== null ? (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
          <Drawer.Screen name="HomeDrawer" component={MainTabScreen} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="SupportScreen" component={SupportScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      )
    :
      <RootStackScreen/>
    }
    </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}
```

export default App;

How can I fix this error so that my drawer opens?

I am using React Native with Expo.

..........................................................................

Comment: Does the open drawer work? can you update the question with the code

Comment: No, open drawer is not working for me.

Comment: I have posted my code above. Please let me know a possible solution to this error.

Comment: Where is your drawer navigator and i dont see a navigation container as well

Comment: I have added my drawer navigator. It is inside my App.js

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with the code, can you try navigation.toggleDrawer() instead of using the actions

Comment: I tried doing that. Its still giving an error. Is there any other way I can make the error go away?

Comment: Generally this error occurs when you drawer is not in the tree, ok try this, instead of using the props from the screen get the props from the options like this options={({ navigation }) => ({ headerLeft: () => (//your code)})

Comment: I tried implementing what you said. The other error went away, but now its giving a different error. Its saying TypeError: navigation.openDrawer is not a function. (In 'navigation.openDrawer()', 'navigation.openDrawer' is undefined). How can I solve this?

Comment: It happens when your drawer is not in the tree, dont see anything with the code as well